# Bootsrap modal is getting the same parameter value from Angular NgFor

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootsrap Modal in my Angular project to ask "Are you sure delete this item"

But when i send itemID to the modal even if i select the 4th item to delete it s always getting first itemId

```
<div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let item of florArray">
    <div class="card shadow p-1 mb-2 bg-white rounded" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>{{item.cubeAreaName}}</h3>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" (click)="editZone(item.cubeAreaID)" type="submit">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" type="submit">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Delete It ?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            If you delete this section please dont forget that you will lose your all related tables that you have
            created for this section
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="deactiveZone(item.cubeAreaID)">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Think that i have five listed item. And i clicked to the 4th item to delete.

> (click)="deactiveZone(item.cubeAreaID)

This code part that exist in the button of modal always deleting first item.

Can you please tell where is my mistake ?

Comment: Would you add an online example, like this https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: You need to store the index of the item clicked , and when deactivateZone is called, use/pass that index to delete the corresponding item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap modals don't work like that. I too had same problems when starting around. What you can do is store the ID in a temporary variable and use it.

TS :

```
. . .
tempIDSelect : number
. . .
```

HTML :

```
. . .
// Button to toggle delete modal
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" type="submit" (click)="tempIDSelect=item.CubeAreaID">Delete</button>
. . .
// Button inside modal
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="deactiveZone(tempIDSelect)">Delete</button>
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you. Working like hell :)